# How to prevent backspace from deleting my shell prompt?

Tags: shell, shell-mode

It is a usual shell display:

```
ME@mycomputer: ~$ echo
```

When I do backspace several times It becomes:

```
ME@mycompu
```

How to prevent the system word from deleting

Comment: Not an answer, but `eshell` doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're looking for `comint-prompt-read-only`.  E.g.

```
(setq comint-prompt-read-only t)
```

should take care of it.

Comment: I don't know if this is a different question, but is it possible to prevent comint from deleting previous output? At the moment I could just move up with my cursor and delete stuff.